# UFW disabled/inactive on reboot

Tags: kubuntu, firewall, ufw

I'm having an odd issue where ufw gets disabled on reboot.
I'm running kubuntu 21.10 and ufw 0.36.1.
My `uname -a` output is: `Linux HOSTNAMEHERE 5.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 24 15:35:05 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

After every reboot ufw seems to be disabled, and `ufw status` reports it as inactive until I manually start it using `ufw enable`, at which point it functions normally until the next reboot.

The ufw service is enabled and started on boot, which indicates that ufw should be functioning, but it is not. Another side effect of this is that it disables my internet connectivity until I run `ufw enable`.
I have also looked through `syslog` and nothing stood out.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check if netfilter-persistent service is enabled on your machine?

   ```
   sudo service --status-all | grep netfilter-persistent
   ```
2. Also, make sure you have **enabled the ufw at boot** using

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable ufw
   ```

not using

```
  sudo ufw enable
```

Comment: Why does command number one return an empty value? I did not understand why we need to check the status of netfilter-persistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
systemctl disable iptables
systemctl stop iptables
```

will work